# Body text reverts to LaTex default

Tags: fonts, fontspec, xltxtra

I've managed to give my sections (chapter, section, subsection) their own specific font (Arial in the code I've pasted in).
But for some reason, the text font, which I've set to be `newpxtext` is gone, replaced by LaTex's default text font.

What have I forgotten?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Arial}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\filcenter\fontsize{30}{30}\headingfont}
{\huge\MakeUppercase\headingfont{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{12pt}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-113pt)$) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}};}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{140pt}{120pt}
\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\headingfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Nice Title}  
\blindtext

\section{A Section Title}
\blindtext

\subsection{Travels}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using the fontspec package? Are you typesetting with xelatex or lualatex?  The ddefault font used by fontspec is Latin modern.

Comment: With fontspec, you might need to use `\setmainfont{newpxtext}` or set it to the actual font name, which might be different.

Comment: @Herb: I am indeed typesetting with xelatex.

Comment: newpxtext is a package to make available a version of the tex gyre fonts for pdftex, with xelatex just use TeX Gyre Pagella directly via fontspec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xltxtra` package loads the following three packages automatically:  `fontspec`, `realscripts`, `metalogo`. Unless you need the capabilities provided by `realscripts` and `metalogo`, you may be better off loading just `fontspec`. At any rate, `newpxtext` should be loaded *after* `xltxtra` (or `fontspec`).

```
\usepackage{xltxtra} % or just 'fontspec'
\usepackage{newpxtext}
```

---

*Addendum*: As David Carlisle has pointed out in a comment, the `newpxtext` package is meant for pdfLaTeX and shouldn't be used with `XeLaTeX`. Better to issue one of the following two instructions (choose one only, not both):

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype} % or, if available on your system, 'Palatino nova'
```

Comment: @nofare newpxtext is a font package for classic tex and should not be used with xelatex. (apart from anything else it sets the encoding to T1 so hyphenation will be incorrect)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the heads up. I originally was using Palatino, but was told to replace it with newpxtext. What would you suggest I use?

Comment: @nofare - The alternative depends on which Palatino look-alikes are installed on your system. I just posted an addendum, suggesting you consider TeX Gyre Pagella, Palatino Linotype, or (if available) Palatino nova.

Comment: Thank you Mico. I'll try these and look into the issue. And thank you all, very much. The Tex crew on StackExchange is plain fantastic.

Comment: @nofare - You're most welcome! :-)